# Issues converting ASPX Web app from .net 3.5 to 4.8.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, upgrade, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.8

I have an older ASPX Web application that I need to upgrade from .net 3.5 to 4.8.1 because we need to move to Windows Server 2022. I am having a hard time finding good resources online around this. Can someone point me at any good articles or give me some steps here?

[image]

Comment: What you ask is a humongous jump. The good books, articles and courses were written 13 years ago when .NET Framework 4.0 was released and replaced 3.5. MSDN (nowadays learn.microsoft.com) contained a *lot* of articles. The WebForms model changed a *lot* and was eventually replaced by MVC architectures. The partial panels needed for "AJAX" calls were eliminated entirely at some point.  Web Services had already changed from ASMX to WCF. The Enterprise Library blocks that people used for logging or data access became obsolete and abandoned. In the 13 years since many features were removed too

Comment: Start from the [.NET Framework Migration Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/), including [How to: Configure an App to Support .NET Framework 4 or later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5)  and [.NET Framework 4 Migration Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/net-framework-4-migration-issues). You can get the existing application to at least start running on 4.x. The `Issues` page explains what will break and fixes if any

Comment: The screenshot shows `System.Web.Extensions` a lot which probably means it's using 3.5-era AJAX. This can be an issue, because a lot of the JS libraries that existed back then changed completely or were discontinued. The browsers themselves changed, dropping or changing a lot of features. 3.5 behaved as if Internet Explorer was the only browser and the scripts it included may have issues working with new browsers

Comment: This will run on a newer version of Windows Server.  ASPX will even run on Azure App Service.  I would question what the real reason to upgrade the framework version is, so the end goal is understood.  Only updating the framework version and moving from ASPX to WebForms would take 2-3 months. Modernizing an app like this can take 6-8 months and a re-write would take even longer.

Comment: @AdamVincent that just delays the inevitable and may not be practical if the application needs to call any API that requires TSL 1.2 or later. It will be hard telling customers to install .NET Framework 3.5 although it's [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows). No customer will accept using obsolete TLS versions or losing the ability to call APIs. In this case a possible option would be to run parts of the application on 3.5 but export anything that needs to talk to other systems to separate, modern projects called through HTTP

Comment: @kyleb why are you migrating to 4.8.1? There may be several reasons, with different mitigations and different ways to get to something runnable

Comment: Well, often a upgrade from 3.5 to 4 is seamless. it really depends on what features were used.  I have OFTEN taken a .net 3.5, and changed the framework to 4.0, and the project built without issues.  If such a project builds in 4.0, then you have a VERY good chance that the project will also build + run as 4.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so we assume that the .net 3.5 site builds from Visual Studio, correct?

so, why not change the .net framework to 4.0, and see if the project builds.

So, this:

[image]

If the project builds?

Then change to 4.8.1

If the project also then builds, then you are quite much done.

So, the first goal is to ensure that the project builds fine as .net 3.5.

If that works, then try 4.0, and build again.

And as noted, if 4.0 works, then try building with 4.8.1

If the project builds, then you just upgraded and are now running 4.8.1.

I find in many cases, that 3.5 applications often upgrade very easy, and a good number of them only required changing the framework and a building the application.

It not clear why many are suggesting that a lot of effort is required for such upgrades, and in the past I have found that a simple upgrading of the project framework from 3.5 to 4.0 and building works fine.

As noted, if the project builds with .net 4.0, then try 4.8.1.

If the project builds, then you just upgraded to .net 4.8.1, and no further code changes are required.

If the projects builds, then try running and testing it. If the project builds and runs? Then this simple change of the .net framework is all you require.

Comment: There is no project file for this. It's just a website folder structure. How do I change .net framework version in web.config. There are many references to 3.5 and there is not .net version or httpruntime node currently like .net 4.0+ has.

Comment: But you are using Visual Studio, and you used file->open web site. At that point, then you right click in project explorer (web site), and then choose property pages. You then choose the build tab. On that tab, you should see the .net framework here.  I mean, all you doing here is changing the .net framework, and doing a build. As I stated, in most cases, that is ALL you require here to upgrade to the next versions of .net. It not like there going to be some code re-written. In rare cases, some features are/will/may have been depreciated, but it's actually quite rare changes are required.

Comment: So, in the build tab, try changing the .net framework from 3.5 to 4. If it builds, then try 4.8.1

Comment: Sorry it had been a while for me changing .net version in .net 3.5 Environment. I changed to .net 4.8.1 from the start and compiled and so far it runs ok. I need to do some more testing, but seems to work...

Comment: Great!! - if that site runs, then you upgraded to 4.8, and it runs just fine. As I stated in the comments, I was not really sure why others were saying this is some huge deal. In most cases, just bumping up the .net framework version will work. I mean, if that was a older .net 2.0, then this is somewhat more difficult. However, the jump from 3.5 to 4.0 not that huge, and if 4.0 works, then REALLY good chance 4.8.1 will also. So, this is great news on your part...